# concurrently' is not working in npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, electron, concurrently

I am getting this error while running npm start to run react scripts and electron parallelly.

```
PS C:\NotMyuserName\user\Desktop\PSlab\pslab-desktop> npm start

> pslab@2.4.0 start C:\Users\user\Desktop\PSlab\pslab-desktop
> concurrently 'npm run react-start' 'wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && npm run electron-start'

[0] ''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[1] 'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[2] 'react-start'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2] operable program or batch file.
[3] ''wait-on' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[3] operable program or batch file.
[4] 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[4] operable program or batch file.
[1] run exited with code 1
[0] 'npm exited with code 1
[4] http://localhost:3000/ exited with code 1
[3] 'wait-on exited with code 1
[2] react-start' exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pslab@2.4.0 start: `concurrently 'npm run react-start' 'wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && npm run electron-start'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pslab@2.4.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\NotMyuserName\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-16T07_13_05_290Z-debug.log
```

versions that I am using:

```
node: v14.15.0
npm:6.14.8
electron:10.1.5
concurrently": "^5.3.0
```

is there are any other way to run react-scripts parallelly with electron without terminating the react operation?